# How do I use linq to fill dictionary with default values?

Tags: c#, linq

Dictionary1 has a key of entities to a string, let's say "Def3".

So it looks like:

```
Ent1, Def3
Ent3, Def3
```

Dictionary2 has all entities associated to another string, that string which is not important.

```
Ent1, Unimportant
Ent2, Unimportant
Ent3, Unimportant
```

I know a default string Def2 I'd like to put into Dictionary1 for every Entity in Dictionary2 that doesn't exist in Dictionary1.

How can I update Dictionary1 such that it looks like:

```
Ent1, Def3
Ent2, Def2
Ent3, Def3
```

Fyi: These are short examples for much larger dictionaries, so simple case-by-case insertion wouldn't work here.

Update: Ok, let me clarify. If Dictionary2 Has a Key that is not a key in Dictionary1, add Dictionary2's Key with a string ("Def2").

Comment: This would be much clearer with a [mcve], not abstract things like `Ent1` and `Def3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var key in Dictionary2.Keys.Where(k => !Dictionary1.Keys.Contains(k)))
{
    Dictionary1.Add(key, defaultstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ for this job:

```
var Dictionary3 = Dictionary2.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
    x => Dictionary1.ContainsKey(x.Key) ? Dictionary1[x.Key] : "Def2");
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` would be preferable to `ContainsKey`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all keys of Dictionary2 that are no keys in Dictionary1 to be added as a key in Dictionary1 with a value def2.

In small steps:

```
var allKeysInDict1 = Dictionary1.Keys;
var allKeysInDict2 = Dictionary2.Keys;
var missingKeysInDict1 = allKeysInDict2.Except(allKeysInDict1);
foreach (var missingKey in missingKeysInDict1)
{
    dictionary1.Add(missingKey, def2);
}
```